# 240V (North America) bridge rectifier with parallel filter capacitors is blowing fuses above the bridge

Tags: bridge-rectifier

[image]

I gained much needed help from this forum in successfully installing a full bridge rectifier on my glass kiln.

Everything has worked very well but I would like to try and filter the ripple voltage with a pair of 200V, 22000uF capacitors in parallel. I have used my process controller to limit the maximum voltage to 185V.

When I applied power to the install, the SCR voltage controller was not working. I found that a pair of superconducting fuses (63A, 240V) placed just above the SCR were blown. Picture of the system without the rectifier/capacitors is attached. They were placed below the 50A breaker (actually 60A) and above the heater.

Does the capacitor pair need to be charged up somehow prior to use in the system? It seems like they are trying to draw too much current and blowing my fuses.

Comment: Inrush current is certainly a factor, but I would be more concerned about the peak voltage (262V) that you are applying to those 200V capacitors.

Comment: I mentioned that I was limiting the voltage to 185V max. I used a meter to test this as DC current exiting the bridge rectifier prior to installing the capacitors.

Comment: Are you limiting the voltage to 185V AC (rms) or 185V DC?

Comment: I measured the output voltage from the rectified current. I set my controller at a 65% power maximum and at full output the meter read 185V. I'm careful not to call the rectified current "DC" as I've been corrected for doing so.

Comment: There are no capacitors in your schematic. Please draw a schematic of your exact setup.

Comment: "*I set my controller at a 65% power maximum and at full output the meter read 185V.*" Your controller is doing phase controlled voltage reduction. At 65% the triacs are on for > half a half-cycle which means that your rectifiers will still be getting peak mains voltage and that's what will determine peak current.

Comment: "*I would like to try and filter the ripple voltage with a pair of 200V, 22000uF capacitors in parallel.*" .. Not possible that way

Comment: How is feeding DC to your heater instead of phase-controlled AC going to improve your system?

Comment: Please check out this posting if you are wondering why I want to do this. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/628207/connecting-a-bridge-rectifier-amazon-8781939822360-to-shop-power-us-240v/628337?noredirect=1#comment1661055_628337

Comment: WHat is your ripple voltage problem? Phase controlled or Burst controlled?

Comment: It's not a ripple voltage problem, I'm just trying to achieve as close to a smooth DC voltage input into the heating elements as I can

Comment: If given the time constant of thermal response to power, what is the temperature ripple?

Comment: current limiter? I contacted Ametherm and they are suggesting an input current limiter be placed above the bridge. Will this prevent damage to my SCR?

Comment: Your schematic is incomplete. You talk about the bridge rectifier and capacitors, but you do not show them. They are essential to addressing your problems.

Comment: I described them as after the SCR and before the heating elements. There is really only one way they could be inserted into the system that way.

Comment: The  document says burst or phase control, which mode is it?

Comment: My SCR is phase angle: DC10-24P0-0000 Watlow SCR Power Controller

Comment: Please note this is a fixed current system with heating elements that draw 48 amps. If a 50amp current limiter before the bridge, how can capacitors stress the SCR? The max it will ever see is 50A which is what the elements always demand. The capacitors will discharge into the elements and temperature readings will be made inside the kiln and the controller will decide how much voltage is needed to achieve or maintain the set point. I can see a slight time discrepancy between direct input and using a capacitor but the controller has many variables that can adjust for this such as cycle time.

Comment: If you have a sine wave, a full-wave rectifier, cap and load; the cap will draw large current pulses for a fraction of the cycle. If you want reasonable ripple, the angle might be 10 degrees. If we assume that the current is constant during this time, It will be 18 times the average at the load (180 deg/10 deg). This circuit has been around forever, so you can find information in books and on the internet. continued ...

Comment: Now if you phase control the input, for phases less than 90 degress, the cap will see a sharp voltage edge and enormous current spikes, not good. If your caps aren't rated for this, they won't last, worst case, they might explode. Without starting over, IMO, a choke is the best hope. See PStechPaul's answer. It may weigh 20+ pounds and cost hundreds of dollars new, maybe you can repurpose something.

Answer (score 3):

Capacitor-input filtering is somewhere between not recommended, and disastrous, for thyristor based phase control.  You need a very large inductor instead.

Note that Vrms or |Vavg| is not Vpk, and the capacitor charges to peak.

Easier to just use some kind of equivalent sine wave control, such as a servo controlled variac, or switching supply.

Hm, I wonder if an ESC (electronic speed controller) would do here.  You would need one for a DC motor, with output filtering.  Hmm, that's probably not a common combination... motor drives tend to be messy affairs (relying on the motor's own inductance for filtering).  Well, it might still switch faster than mains frequency, meaning less inductance needed.

Comment: In my system, how is the SCR affected by the bridge rectifier and capacitors? It is supplying an AC current that is getting processed to "DC-like" prior to entering the heating coils.

Comment: @DanielVanAntwerp Bridge doesn't matter, beyond that it allows charging the capacitor in one direction. SCR firing into a capacitor, then, causes huge inrush current, as the capacitor was discharged by the load, then charged suddenly up to whatever voltage the SCR turns on at. With a pure resistive load, this doesn't happen and the load simply receives a variable fraction of mains.  With a capacitor load, inrush current occurs, evidently enough to blow the fuse -- and indeed indicating unsafe operation.

Comment: Can I use an input current limiter?

Comment: An input current limiter such as the NTC thermistors recommended by Ametherm may help reduce the initial turn-on surge, but there will likely be repeated high current spikes when the SCR turns on near peak voltage. As I recommended in your other Q&A, why not switch over to 120 VAC line voltage, where the controller will switch on near the zero crossing. There will also be a lot less dI/dt and dV/dt noise, which also may cause mechanical vibration and induced RF that could be the cause of your problems discussed elsewhere.

Comment: @PStechPaul Thanks for your input. My kiln controller, like most any glass kiln, is built around 240 volts. The (expensive) SCR (DC10-24P0-0000 Watlow) needs 240V input. If 120V did not work I would not want to switch over just to find out. The system is fine while holding 2150-2250F at about 100-125V but sometimes it asks for more power when it thinks it needs it. I don't want to limit the power if a 240V system can be configured. I've described my setup to Ametherm and due to the high current he also mentioned adding a relay bypass. I will ask about the current spikes at peak voltage.

Answer (score 1):

I have made three simulations for the OP's circuit, assuming a resistive load of 20 ohms (2880 watts at 240V) and a phase angle of 90 degrees. The first one shows what we have without any filtering:

[image: Unfiltered DC output]

Notice that the output is 167 VRMS and 106 VDC (Average). This produces 1.41 kW for the heating element.

The next simulation shows what happens when you put 44,000 uF of capacitance on the output of the bridge rectifier.

[image: 44,000 uF capacitor on output]

Note that the first current pulse is almost 6000 amps, and then as the capacitors charge up to peak value of 321 VDC the pulses are about 100A. This is a dangerous overvoltage on 200V capacitors, and it produces 5 kW to the heating element.

The third simulation adds a 10 mH choke, which is probably about what you could get from a microwave oven transformer.

[image: 10 mH inductor and 44,000 uF capacitor on output]

Here the maximum current surge is 230A and the output stabilizes at about 195 VDC which provides about 1.9 kW to the heater.

Comment: Well done. I agree that a choke is the answer. Does your C1 model have any ESR? What is the steady state voltage ripple?

Comment: No ESR, so realistic value might be 200 mOhms and thus 1700A. Ripple is about 1.14V P-P. I hope the OP takes note of this and adds a choke. And also he should connect the capacitors in series with 10k 5W bleeder/balancing resistors to get 400 VDC rating.

Comment: WOW! Thanks for putting so much time into this! I am in the process of specing a 50A current limiter placed above the bridge

Comment: The actual element setup is 22 AMP-2600 WATT (EA) 4 IN KILN, 2 SETS OF 2 IN SERIES. How would these current surges ever be realized with a limiter in place above the bridge. The elements are at a fixed ~50A and if I limit the current ask of the capacitors...problem solved?

Comment: Would these resistors work? https://www.amazon.com/10pcs-Royal-Ohm-Sand-Resistor/dp/B00VVZCPBU  Do they connect in series between the capacitors?

Comment: Those are fine. They are connected across the terminals of each capacitor. Then the capacitors are wired in series to get 10,000 uF at 400V. You should make a good schematic showing your entire circuit. And you should provide details on the current limiter you intend to use. The choke is by far the best, simplest, cheapest, and most reliable.

Comment: The techs at Ametherm have concluded that thermistors are not a good idea. Thank you so much for providing a workable solution! Could you tell me where the choke connects in the circuit? I can make out the bridge and the capacitors in your simulation but it's hard for me to tell how this translates into an installation. Also, is 10,000uF going to be enough to smooth the ripple voltage or should I consider adding more?

Comment: I'm also finding lots of 10mH choke coils but with a variety of current maximums. Will a microwave transformer choke coil work ok at 50A? Mouser sells a 10mH, 50A choke coil for over $700!

Comment: The choke will go between the positive terminal of the rectifier bridge and the positive terminal of the top capacitor, which in turn goes to the heating element. 10,000 uF should be plenty. You would need to remove the windings of the MOT and rewind with maybe 20-50 turns of #8 to #12 insulated wire or the equivalent with parallel turns. It will also probably need an air gap in the core to get a useful choke. Search the internet for many articles about using MOTs, especially the safety precautions!

Comment: Any tests or measurements that could be taken on the modified MOT to confirm that it is  within the parameters to be used within my circuit?

Comment: As a first order approximation, consider that a MOT typically exhibits about 0.7 to 1 turn per volt. So the 120 VAC primary likely has 120-150 turns. If it draws 100 mA with no load, that translates to an impedance of 1200-1500 ohms, which is 3.2 t0 4 H. With 1/10 the number of turns, inductance will be 1/100, or about 32 to 40 mH. An air gap will reduce the inductance by a factor of 3 or 4, which will give you the desired 10 mH. But I think anything from 2 mH and up will work well enough. With 2 mH and 10,000 uF, you'll get 250 VDC with 26V P-P ripple, and max 283A input surge.

Comment: You should invest in some test equipment, particularly a cheap scope, and perhaps an LCR meter. Also, perhaps download the FREE LTSpice from https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html. Very good for learning how circuits and components work, as well as a great way to show schematics.

Comment: Thank you, sir! I appreciate your passing on knowledge. I've been looking at getting a scope to see the wave shapes being generated and found an instruction wiki on using an LCR meter.  Any concerns that the primary is rated for 120V and relatively low current?

Comment: Sorry, I think I see that I will be removing both the primary and secondary windings and just adding a new primary. I watched a video on making a transformer which required the primary be retained with a new secondary added but now I see the difference. Please let me know if I have it correct.

Comment: Will the 230A current surge continue to blow my fuses above the SCR?

Comment: No, they reduce to 50A peak after 20 mSec. Of course that is with only 2 mH, and 3.2 kW into a 20 ohm load. You will have to make your own measurements. And make sure that the windings you add are well insulated from the frame, which should be grounded.

Comment: I watched an induction coil video which suggested placing a diode across the coil to prevent a "Flyback" voltage spike when power is removed. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-E12DlzGGc @3:30. Is this the same kind of short lived surge that can be somewhat ignored?

Comment: No, in this case the inductor needs to be able to have both positive and negative voltage transients across it, so the diode would interfere with that. The current surges are due to the charging and discharging of the filter capacitor, and the inductor provides energy storage and release during the zero crossings of the applied rectified voltage.

Comment: Hello again. I am back to this project and have stripped down a MOT. I just need some clarity on adding an air gap. I watched a video for making a custom power supply from an MOT and an air gap was added by using a spacer during winding on the outside of the MOT. Is this what you are suggesting or do I need something more significant such as an actual gap slotted into the metal core (like the air gap described on Figure 6 of this site: http://dicks-website.eu/coilcalculator/ )?

Comment: I think it's time for you to ask another question, titled "How to make an inductor from a microwave oven transformer". You may want to qualify it by including the parameters for your application, particularly that it is for providing ripple reduction for a 48A 240 VAC heater load regulated by a phase fired SCR controller and capacitors. You will need to take apart the transformer, as shown in https://www.instructables.com/Easiest-Microwave-MOT-SalvageRe-use-Tutorial/, and do some testing. You may need to buy a scope.